# java Message displayed sender name/surname

Tags: java, email

I'm using in a java application the `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` to send mail message via `javax.mail` library.

In the message creation class I use something like:

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("name.surname@domain.com"));
```

The message when received show in the message header:

```
From: <name.surname@domain.com>
```

with any mail client software is possible to specify the 'displayed' sender, and in that case the header looks like:

```
From: Name Surname <name.surname@domain.com>
```

where "Name Surname" is a free string, like also "CompanyName commercial office", and it is what in general mail client shows about message sender.

How can I set the 'displayed' sender into the message object? `message.setFrom(String s)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the constructor with the personal parameter:

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("name.surname@domain.com","Name Surname"));
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29